# First differences of columns in a dataframe with non-syntactic names

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Minimal example: I have a dataframe whose column names are non-syntactic - they start with a number

```
set.seed(1)    
df <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2020-03-01"), as.Date("2020-03-5"), by = "days"),
                     DSG1 = sample(-10:10, 5, replace=T),
                     DSG2 = sample(-10:10, 5, replace=T),
                     DSG3 = sample(-10:10, 5, replace=T)
    )
    colnames(df) <- c("Date", "1 Yr.", "2 Yr.", "3 Yr.")


df
        Date 1 Yr. 2 Yr. 3 Yr.
1 2020-03-01    -7     3    10
2 2020-03-02    -4     7    -1
3 2020-03-03   -10     8     3
4 2020-03-04    -9   -10    -1
5 2020-03-05     0    10    -4
```

I would like to get the first differences of all the columns other than the date column in this dataframe (i.e.  row_n = row_n - row_n-1). How can i do this in dplyr? I tried

```
mycols <- colnames(df)[-1]
df[, mycols]
  1 Yr. 2 Yr. 3 Yr.
1    -7     3    10
2    -4     7    -1
3   -10     8     3
4    -9   -10    -1
5     0    10    -4

diff(df[, mycols])
```

but get an error message

```
Error in r[i1] - r[-length(r):-(length(r) - lag + 1L)] : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Many thanks in advance

Thomas Philips

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`diff` doesn't work on dataframes. You can apply it to multiple columns with `across` -

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(across(-Date, ~c(NA, diff(.))))

#        Date 1 Yr. 2 Yr. 3 Yr.
#1 2020-03-01    NA    NA    NA
#2 2020-03-02     3     4   -11
#3 2020-03-03    -6     1     4
#4 2020-03-04     1   -18    -4
#5 2020-03-05     9    20    -3
```

Or you can also use `lag` -

```
df %>% mutate(across(-Date, ~. - lag(.)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
nm1 <- setdiff(names(df), 'Date')
setDT(df)[, (nm1) :=  .SD - shift(.SD), .SDcols = nm1]
```